# R select one row from duplicated rows after compare multi conditions

Tags: r

I got these duplicated records from ton of data. Now, I need to choose one row from these duplicated rows.

```
ID <- c("6820","6820","17413","17413","38553","38553","52760","52760","717841","717841","717841","747187","747187","747187")
date <- c("2014-06-12","2015-06-11","2014-05-01","2014-05-01","2014-06-12","2015-06-11","2014-10-24","2014-10-24","2014-05-01","2014-05-01","2014-12-02","2014-03-01","2014-05-12","2014-05-12")
type <- c("ST","ST","MC","MC","LC","LC","YA","YA","YA","YA","MC","LC","LC","MC")
level <-c("firsttime","new","new","active","active","active","firsttime","new","active","new","active","new","active","active")
data <- data.frame(ID,date,type,level)
```

The data frame will look like this:
[image]

I want to compare this: for each ID,if their dates are different, then keep all of them in df.right; if the date is same, then compare type, choose them in order of LC>MC>YA>ST (eg. choose MC over YA), put them into df.right; if type is same, then compare level, choose them in order of active>new>firsttime (eg. choose new over first time), and put the choosen into df.right.

I tried to use foreach, this is only on the first step, and it is not working for ID have 3 duplicated rows.

```
foreach (i=unique(data$ID), .combine='rbind') %do% {data[data$ID==i, "date"][1] == data[data$ID==i, "date"][2])
b <- data[data$ID==i,]}
```

The result should be like this:
[image]
Does anybody knows how to do this? really appreciate it. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The `dplyr` package is good for this sort of thing

Using factors, you can specify how you want your categories ordered. Then you can pick the first of each type and level for each unique ID/date pair.

```
library(dplyr)

ID <- c("6820","6820","17413","17413","38553","38553","52760","52760","717841","717841","717841","747187","747187","747187")
date <- c("2014-06-12","2015-06-11","2014-05-01","2014-05-01","2014-06-12","2015-06-11","2014-10-24","2014-10-24","2014-05-01","2014-05-01","2014-12-02","2014-03-01","2014-05-12","2014-05-12")
type <- c("ST","ST","MC","MC","LC","LC","YA","YA","YA","YA","MC","LC","LC","MC")
level <-c("firsttime","new","new","active","active","active","firsttime","new","active","new","active","new","active","active")

type <- factor(type, levels=c("LC", "MC", "YA", "ST"))

level <- factor(level, levels=c("active", "new", "firsttime"))

data <- data.frame(ID,date,type,level)

df.right <- data %>%
  group_by(ID, date) %>%
  filter(type == sort(type)[1]) %>%
  filter(level == sort(level)[1])
```

Comment: i don't think that answer produces the correct output

Comment: @pcantalupo It doesn't exactly match OP's sample output, but I think OP's sample output is incorrect as between rows 13 and 14, 13 is the one that should be kept (instead of 14) because LC has priority over MC

Comment: hmm, I was wondering why things didn't seem just right about that.

Comment: This is very elegant; the improvement I would suggest is to use `arrange` to sort by type and level, and then use `top_n` to pull out the top element; so after the `group_by`, just `arrange(type, level) %>% top_n(1)`

Answer (score 1):

The trick here is to order the levels of `type` and `level` as appropriate. Then two deduplications are necessary: first, to remove duplicate rows based on the columns `ID, date, type` and second, remove dup rows based upon first two columns:

```
type = factor(type, levels=c("ST","YA","MC","LC"))
level = factor(level, levels=c("active","new","firsttime"))
data <- data.frame(ID,date,type,level)

d = with(data, data[order(ID, date, type, level),])
e = d[-which(duplicated(d[,1:3])),]
df.right = e[-which(duplicated(e[,1:2])),]
df.right = df.right[order(as.numeric(as.character(df.right$ID)), df.right$date),]
df.right
```

Output:

```
       ID       date type     level
1    6820 2014-06-12   ST firsttime
2    6820 2015-06-11   ST       new
4   17413 2014-05-01   MC    active
5   38553 2014-06-12   LC    active
6   38553 2015-06-11   LC    active
8   52760 2014-10-24   YA       new
9  717841 2014-05-01   YA    active
11 717841 2014-12-02   MC    active
12 747187 2014-03-01   LC       new
14 747187 2014-05-12   MC    active
```